# How to Display Text on Textbox depending on the Combobox Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. I have two columns:

Column 1
a
b
c

Column 2
1
2
3

So in if I select a from the combo box - I wanted to text box to show 1.

I have been trying to figure it out through the other posts here but could not get it to work.

If you could explain it to me that would be great!

```
  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ComboBox1.List = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use VLOOKUP on the combobox value and put this code in the combo box change event so that it runs whenever it is changed. Or you could assign it to a button.

Amend control names as necessary.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Application.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, 2, 0)
End Sub
```